# SwiftUI form section title and rows have incorrect formatting

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-form

The following SwiftUI form will render the section its header and contents incorrectly. The section header should be capitalized and have a background color. The rows should be marked up like a list, meaning, they should have list separators and padding.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Test")) {
                    ForEach(0..<5) { index in
                        Text("Row \(index)")
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {}, label: { Text("Dummy") }))
            }
            .navigationTitle(Text("Navigation title"))
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Incorrectly rendered section header and rows]

Answer (score 3):

The cause of the incorrect formatting is that the `.navigationBarItems` should not be attached to the `Section` but instead moved lower, to the `Form`:

```
Form {
    Section(header: Text("Test")) {
        ForEach(0..<5) { index in
            Text("Row \(index)")
        }
    }
}
.navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {}, label: { Text("Dummy") }))
.navigationTitle(Text("Navigation title"))
```

This renders the form correctly:

[image: Correctly rendered form]

If you use the newer `.toolbar` modifier and attach it to the `Section`, the section will render correctly but the button simply won't show up. However `.toolbar` is only usable from iOS 14 and up.